# Join Derived Table Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I want to be able to define a derived table. How do I define that using the find method of the model?

```
select *
from tableA
join (
   select *
   from tableB
) as DerivedTable on tableA.id = tableB.id
```

Comment: I think you need to write custom query

Comment: Any particular reason this doesn't serve your purpose: `select * from tablea join tableb on (tablea.id = tableb.id)` ? Is your _actual_ query different than the question (if so ask a real question to get a real answer)? You can put whatever you want in the [joins key](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find) of a find. Alternatively: what have you tried, what happened and in what way is that different from what you want?

Comment: sorry, i should have been more elaborate. i made the derived table simple for the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Model associations like you would with any other join, but just set an alternative foreignKey in your association. For example in ModelA.php

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'ModelB' => array(
        'className' => 'ModelB',
        'foreignKey' => 'id' // Use just id, instead of default modelb_id
    )
);
```